# Scrollview Android how to start at determinate position

Tags: android, scrollview

I have this layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centro">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/welcometoflorida"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sf_boton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/southfloridacover" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cf_boton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/centralfloridacover" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nf_boton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/northfloridcover" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fb_boton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/floridabeaches" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tfry_boton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ridescover" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sd_boton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shoppingcover" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/da_boton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/discovermapcover" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I want when user scroll the view move the way like this 2 pictures.

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By7CZpKC1ijIMlNFSDZSUmlhLU0/view?usp=sharing
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By7CZpKC1ijIUGZmTml3bWJYQTA/view?usp=sharing

My scroll is like the first view but when I start scrolling only move the items in the current place. I want to scroll like the second image.

Answer (score 0):

try this for Example

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <HorizontalScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
   android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/twitter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="256dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/twitterbirdicon500" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/google"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twitter"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/google500" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/linkedin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="256dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/google"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/linkedin500" />

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/face500" />

     </RelativeLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```